# Is my outside sewer cleanout a straight line from my basement drain?

Tags: plumbing, sewer

I'm trying to locate my sewer cleanout outside the house. Is it **usually** just a straight line from my basement drain hole?

Answer (score 3):

98% of the time the answer is no.  It is a straight line from the bottom of your main stack.  The drain hole is a branch off your main stack.   This can vary though but this is the norm in the US.

Comment: and I can't use a snake through the basement drain hole, because it has a u-trap?

Comment: It is probably a larger u-trap so you can probably get past that.  If your issue is in between your main stack and drain then give it a try.  If you problem is outside your house you are probably wasting your time.

Comment: My basement drain is starting to backup, and I can't find a cleanout inside or outside the house. So frustrating.

Comment: There will be a cleanout in your yard for sure.  Also you should have one in your main stack and quite possibly on your roof.